# How to re.compile a variable in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner. This seems so simple, but I have spent hours searching and trying different things with no luck. I want to express the string I am compiling as a variable.

### So this works:

```
p = re.compile("['4c']")

for m in p.finditer('234567891JQKA'):
    q = str(m.start() + 2)
```

### While this doesn't:

```
card = ['4c']
p = re.compile(card)

for m in p.finditer('234567891JQKA'):
    q = str(m.start() + 2)
```

In my program card is constantly changing. How do I do this?

### The error I get is:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 223, in compile
return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 282, in _compile
p, loc = _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: `str(['4c'])` gives `"['4c']"`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile

Comment: What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure the first pattern is what you actually want,  what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks...p = re.compile(str(card))  works perfectly. Sorry for such a simple question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your second example is that you assign `['4c']` (a *list*) to `card` rather than `"['4c']"` (the *string* that works in your first example).  [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) expects a string pattern.

Adjust as follows, and your second example will work like your first example:

```
import re # added for clarity

card = "['4c']"
#      ^      ^
p = re.compile(card)

# or

card = ['4c']
p = re.compile(str(card))  # str(card) == "['4c']"
#              ^^^^    ^

for m in p.finditer('234567891JQKA'):
    q = str(m.start() + 2)
    # added for clarity
    print m.start()  # prints 2
    print q          # prints 4
```

***Having said this***, the pattern `"['4c']"` seems suspect.  At minimum, `'` is redundant within the [regex character set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (bounded by the opening `[` and the closing `]`): make sure `card` is a string that specifies a sensible regex pattern for your needs.

Comment: Not mine but your code is exactly the same as the OP's first example so you have not really answered the question *How to re.compile a variable in Python*, the OP has a variable so telling them to manually change it is not really going to be very helpful

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: My code is not exactly the same as the OP's first example.  Please, re-read both.  They are clearly different -- the variable `card` being the key difference...and the crux of what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two mistakes in your program

**First, a strange Regex wildcard**

You suppose to read at least a basic regex before you using it, you explicitly misunderstand it, here some useful [cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) and [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile).

`['4c']` (wrong! it stands for either one character `'`, `4` or `c` but there is duplicated `'`)

`['4c]` (right! it stands for either one character `'`, `4` or `c`),

`[4c']` (right! it stands for either one character `'`, `4` or `c`),

`[4c]` (right! it stands for either one character `4` or `c`)

**Second, Python list != Regex wildcard**

`['4c']` is a list which contains string `'4c'`,

`"['4c']"` is a string which contain regular expression wildcard.

Finally, if you prefer to use the second form of your code, your code suppose to look like this

```
card = "['4c']" # not clear here what you want to do
p = re.compile(card)

for m in p.finditer('234567891JQKA'):
    q = str(m.start() + 2)
```

Comment: Respectfully, this is essentially what I answered *half an hour* prior, in opposite order of importance (given the problem statement).  Rather than (largely) re-hashing an answer, please comment on and help improve it.  Others should do the same for you of course.

Comment: Honestly, I do not even read what did you answer, the question is very short, scope of answer is very narrow, the same idea of answer is not unexpected. what I just expect here, just hope that either your answer or my answer can help him, that's all.

Comment: Fair enough.  That happens; it has happened to me, and I have explained it the same way.  Thirty minutes is just a *long* time to not note another answer to a question you are answering.